# Convert maps to list of maps in Kotlin

Tags: list, dictionary, kotlin

I am trying to convert a traditional map:

```
1 -> "YES",
2 -> "NO",
3 -> "YES",
...
```

To a list of maps with fixed keys like such:

```
[
  <number -> 1,
   answer -> "YES">,
  <number -> 2,
   answer -> "NO">,
  ...
]
```

Right now I have a solution which does not look good and is not really making use of Kotlin's functional features. I was wondering if there was a clearer solution that did:

```
fun toListOfMaps(map: Map<Int, String>): List<Map<String, Any>> {
    val listOfMaps = emptyList<Map<String, Any>>().toMutableList()

    for (entry in map) {
        val mapElement = mapOf(
                "number" to entry.component1(),
                "answer" to entry.component2()
        )
        listOfMaps.add(mapElement)
    }

    return listOfMaps
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to use [Map#map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) is sufficient for you, for example:

```
fun toListOfMaps(map: Map<Int, String>): List<Map<String, Any>> {
    //               v--- destructuring `Map.Entry` here
    return map.map { (number, answer) -> 
        mapOf("number" to number, "answer" to answer) 
    }
}
```